# inclusion of filtration

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, filtrations

Let $(\Omega,F,P)$ be probability space  and $T>0$, let  $\lbrace W(t), 0\leqslant t\leqslant T\rbrace $ be SBM and $F^W_{s,t}=\sigma \lbrace W(r)-W(s); s\leqslant r\leqslant t\rbrace \vee N$
with $N$ the class of P-null sets of $ F$.
My question is why $F^W_{t,T} \subset F^W_{0,T}$?

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed $r\in [t,T]$ one has $W(r)-W(t) = W(r)-W(0)- (W(t)-W(0)) $ and the quantities on the RHS are all $F_{0,T}^W$ measurable.  To be more precise
$$ P(W(r)-W(t)<x) = P(\bigcap_{q\in \mathbb Q \cap [0,x]} \{W(r)-W(0)<q\}\cap \{-(W(t)-W(0))<x-q\}) $$
due to continuity of the Brownian motion. The symmetric difference of the two sets in the above equation is of probability 0, hence they are almost surely equal. The left set is in $F_{t,T}^W$ while the right set is in $F_{0,T}^W$.

Comment: thank you but i didn't understand why you said that " The symmetric difference of the two sets in the above equation is of probability 0"

Comment: Basically the set on the LHS of the equation and the one on the RHS are almost surely the same.